# Technology/Platform Recommendations for javascript Outlook Add-In

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am looking to develop an Outlook Javascript Web Add-In and was wondering if people had specific technologies that they would recommend, or more importantly, not recommend based on past experiences.
The main "gotchas" that I can think of are:

- compliance across different browser platforms (e.g. Chrome, IE);  though I believe a Webpack should take care of this.
- complications with having a sandbox browser loaded inside Outlook (e.g. X-Frame-Options: DENY)

The basic functionality of the add-in would be to:
- access the Exchange item fields (e.g. email addresses, Subject, parsed words from body), send them to an API and display the response data
- Access to this UI and API will be secured by some Identity Access Management system like Okta or Keycloak

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) + [Fluent UI](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/) (React UI). Everything else is up to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/learning-path-beginner#:%7E:text=The%20primary%20programming%20language%20you,strongly%2Dtyped%20version%20of%20JavaScript.), it's recommended to use Javascript or Typescript.

And, we can explore the Office JavaScript APIs with the [Script Lab tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab) -- a sandbox for running and exploring the APIs.